# Power Apps - How to move environment variables to other environment

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, office365-apps, powerapps-modeldriven

We are working on a power apps solution where we have added everything in a solution (unmanaged)- Flows, Variables, Connection references etc. Now while moving this app to UAT environment we want to split this solution into 2- Managed and Unmanaged.
Managed will have variables and connection ref & Unmanaged will have rest everything.
So is this possible to do? If yes, then how?
I have checked some references and didnt found any way to find this.

Comment: What’s the reason for wanting to do that?